# Protractor test is not starting on Firefox

Tags: protractor

I have got a set of test that run fine on chrome but when I change the capabilities browserName from chrome to firefox don't even get a error info

```
//Before
   capabilities: {
         'browserName': 'chrome',
         'chromeOptions': { args: ['--test-type', 'show-fps-counter=true'] }
    },

//After
   capabilities: {
          'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with firefox, basically my protractor config was not using any webdriver server setting but was using the default server, this way was quite handy since did not have start selenium by my self

In order to fix this issue I am starting selenium server by myself spesifiying firefox and chrome drivers

> java -jar "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.1.jar" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that firefox 35,36 is not supported by protractor so one workaround is to download [firefox 34 here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/34.0/) and set its path by adding

```
"firefox_binary": "path/to/custom/firefox"
"binary_": "path/to/custom/firefox"
```

in your conf file as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26170282/2149366) by [@6220119](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800699/6220119)