# How can I configure the firefox binary location in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, windows, testing, firefox, protractor

I am successfully running Protractor tests with Chrome, specifying the path to my chrome binary using the following section in my Protractor configuration:

```
capabilities: {
// You can use other browsers
// like firefox, phantoms, safari, IE
'browserName': 'chrome',
"chromeOptions": {
  binary: 'C:/BuildSoftware/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
}
```

This works.

My Firefox is also installed in a non-standard location.

Is there an equivalent way to specify the binary for Firefox in the protractor config?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATED:** See newer answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313583/800699

It seems you have to start the Selenium Server by yourself with custom arguments for firefox driver. 
See [Protractor test is not starting on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991370/protractor-test-is-not-starting-on-firefox)

More options for firefox driver (including custom firefox binary location) can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

P/S: Browsing the firefox driver source reveals more light:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js

You can try adding:

```
"browserName": "firefox",
"firefox_binary": "path/to/custom/firefox",
"binary_": "path/to/custom/firefox"
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is true. See Julie's comment here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/483.

Answer (score 6):

Protractor now supports setting the firefoxPath directly in the configuration file, when using "direct connect" (i.e., without a selenium server).  See the reference config file:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L67

Add `firefoxPath` to the config file, at the top-level.  It is a string that should be the path to your firefox binary.  You will also need `directConnect: true` in the config.

For more details (handy to see all the doc that changed at once) check out [the change that added this support (in Oct 2014)](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/adef9b208fcba2a9d60347bda38a3fe3fac6bf50).

Answer (score 4):

It's 2018 and it appears you can set a specific `binary` argument within the `'moz:firefoxOptions'` section of the capabilities like so:

```js
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: [...Your args here...],
        binary: '/Path/To/Custom/firefox'
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I ran this with `directConnect: true` in my protractor config also. I'm not sure if it works if you're passing the command to the Selenium server.

Reference: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/README.md#mozfirefoxoptions

Answer (score 1):

I added my custom binary location to PATH variable.

```
export PATH="/custom-firefox-location:$PATH"
```

That makes my custom firefox version to be available during the session and when running protractor it uses that.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate **Monkpit's** answer which is correct .Below code is  worked for me , verified and tested in protractor v 5.4.2 .
Only thing is needed to open the cmd via admin mode to avoid the permission error since I installed Firefox in program files.

```
 capabilities: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--verbose'],
            binary: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
       //Need to start cmd via admin mode to avoid permission error
        }
},   
    Full code 

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  directConnect: false, //Start protractor without start the selenium server using webdriver-manager start. default value is fales
  //This is  only for chrome and firefox and use drivers instead of selenium server

  capabilities: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: ['--verbose'],
            binary: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
       //Need to start cmd via admin mode to avoid permission error
        }
},   
    //set to true So each spec will be executed in own browser instance. default value is false
    //restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
     jasmineNodeOpts: {
    //Jasmine provides only one timeout option  timeout in milliseconds don't add ;
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
     },

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/iframes.spec.js']

}
```